# How to instal Pg-Trgm on Windows?

Tags: postgresql, installation, windows

I am currently working on a computer with windows 7 on it and i need to instal the Pg-Trgm module for postgresql 9-5. I have to admit that i am kind of lost here since i don't have any idea how to do this on a windows workspace.

I need it for matching text based columns between them and for some slight manipulations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pg_trgm` extension should already be available with PostgreSQL 9.5 on Windows (supposing you installed via the official installer). This means that there is no need to *install* it, however you need to *activate* it in each database that need to use it.

The only thing left to activate it should be to run the following SQL code:

`CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;`

Another way to do it is via pgAdmin :

- Right-click on ***Extensions*** and select ***New Extension...***
- Choose your extension from the drop-down menu in the ***Name*** field and click OK.

[image: Install extension from pgAdmin]

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, worked perfectly. Thank you